# I am using ubntu 22.04, I am cannot open file or folder using double click. It does not work for double tap of touchpad

Tags: gnome, mouse, doubleclick

I cannot ope file or folder using double click, it does not open for double tap of touch pad .just after start ubuntu it does work. but after few minutes the issue is appeared

also when i turn off comoputer "@@@@@@@@@@@@" appeared on black screen

Comment: Can you provide steps for us so we could eventually reproduce the issue?